# How can a key be part of value in a hash?

Tags: perl

The following is my hash. I don't want to repeat the key (`city` & `country`) in the value part.

```
%sql_cache = (
city => "select * from city where id=106",
country => "select * from country where code='IND'",
);
```

is there any inbuilt variable to achieve that in Perl?

Comment: I don't get what your asking. Those look like unique queries.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this?

```perl
my %sql_cache = (
    city => "select * from %s where id=106",
    country => "select * from %s where code='IND'",
);

# use it
printf "$sql_cache{$_}\n", $_ for keys %sql_cache;
```

Comment: Using `map` in void context is frowned upon: the purpose of this function is to *transform* a list, not to iterate it. Use the statement modifier `for` in cases like this: `printf "$sql_cache{$_}\n", $_ for keys %sql_cache;`. It is also worth noting that string interpolation opens the doors for SQL injection. Also bad: passing (untrusted?) runtime patterns to `printf`.

Comment: @ravi06: Please *don't* do this. It saves very little and makes the code much less clear. Are you trying to reduce typing? If not then what is your goal?

Comment: @amon: I admit it's a bad idea use `map` in this case. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Borodin: I just wanted to fine tune the hash by avoiding repetition of same strings.

Comment: @ravi06: What does *"fine tune"* mean? What are you aiming to *achieve* by removing this repetition? It looks like you may have misunderstood the *"don't repeat yourself"* principle.